# Background for a specific layout in style

Tags: android, android-theme

I have about `8 themes in my app`, I need to have a specific drawable background `(XML shape)` for the login page only,  and that can be changed when I change the theme.

> **Here is my default theme:**

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="CommonDark">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/whiteTrasparentTheme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/whiteTrasparentTheme</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/whiteTrasparentTheme</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/BlackButtonText</item>
    <item name="timerColor">@color/yellowTheme</item>
    <item name="timerTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="iconTinting">@color/yellowThemeIcon</item>
    <item name="iconBG">@color/yellowThemeSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Any help is appreciated.

> **Screenshots**

This is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkdlK.jpg

This is what I have on all my themes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkykW.jpg

Comment: can you explain what you wanted to do ..?

Comment: A background shape to be added to one layout (login page) and it can be controlled by the style, so, every theme will have a different login style and colors

Comment: so what you wanted to do ..? do you want to create new stale theme or something else.. could you please upload any design ?

Comment: I have uploaded 2 screenshots, so, the one I want is the colored background and I want it to be applied only to my default theme in the login page, so, the rest of the layouts are still white after the login

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to create a my_background_login.xml in drawable package :

in this xml you have to put this code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#555994"
    android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
    android:startColor="#555994"
    android:type="linear" />

     <corners 
    android:radius="0dp"/>

    </shape>
```

you have specify your start color , center color and end color in xml..
then set this drawable as background in your main parent layout, so whenever you want to change you can directly change from this xml.

this is the proper way to get it done..

try it

Comment: Thanks, I have that already, I just need to apply it ONLY to the login page via STYLE.XML